# Same class name in same namespace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, namespaces

I'm working on a web-project and I was asked to move some files from a project to another project, but both of the projects are in the same solution. So I migrate File1 from project A to project B. However, I have a "Foo" namespace in File1 with a class called "Bar". However, I have a "Foo" namespace in project B too and in the other "Foo" namespace I have another "Bar" class. How can I solve the issue, knowing that renaming a namespace or a class is not an option?

Thank you,

Lajos Árpád.

Comment: Apparently you cannot unless you wanna merge the Bar classes by making them both partial classes.

Comment: Its not much of a migration if you can't change the class or namespace. Two classes in the same assembly cannot have the same class name and namespace. There is a way to do this if the classes are in different assemblies but, that doesent't apply here.

Comment: Do not name a class the same as its namespace.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: @Jodrell, I have a DLL which can't be changed linked to the B project and generated classes are defined in the B project. So it is not an option to rename any of them. I have found the solution to the problem but I don't share it as an answer just yet because I have to do a lot of testing. When I complete the testing if nobody answers the question I will answer it myself.

Comment: @LajosArpad, your comment describes a different situation to the one in your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem by giving a default namespace to the B project, so the given namespace generated at the B project was finally inside the default namespace of the project and the namespace which came from the DLL remained outside the default namespace of the project.

Comment: So, you changed the namespace which, you stated, you couldn't do.

Comment: I've changed the default namespace of the project, so the location of the namespace was different, but I didn't change the namespace, it is the same, but it is located elsewhere in the graph of namespaces.

Comment: If this is a VB.Net project, it has no "default" namespace.  It has a "root" namespace which, when compiled, becomes part of the namespace of the class, so in effect, you *did* change the namespace.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a root namespace. But I didn't change my namespace, it became a namespace inside the root when the root was defined. However, I didn't change my namespace, I've added a root, thus the location of the namespace has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you have two options:

1. Rename on of the classes or namespaces
2. Merge both Bar classes (you can make them both partial, or merge them by moving code from one to another)

Comment: Nope, in my case renaming classes and namespaces is not an option, as I described in my question. The two Bar classes are conceptually very different, they don't belong together, your second option would only be feasible if and only if the two classes are not very different.

Comment: @LajosArpad if changing the namespaces is not an option, why is it your answer?

Comment: I didn't change the namespace, I've changed something else, which is the default namespace of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. You either need to change the namespace or the class name of either the source or target.

Comment: I've managed to do this, as decsribed in my answer. All my tests were successful.